# Tkinter '<Configure>' event prevents widgets from loading properly

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently coding a small app in Tkinter and need to resize a Frame any time the window is resized to keep the aspect ratio of the frame.

I have used the **Configure** event for that. However, when using this event, the widgets of the window do not show up until I hover my mouse above them.

I, of course, don't want this behaviour to happen.

I have tried binding the configure event to the root window before and after the creation of all the widgets. Without success.
Furthermore, I have tried waiting before I call the configure event with the sleep method.

I have also tried adding a thread which executes binds the event a few seconds later. It does work but when I create new widgets, those new widgets are not properly loaded. I was wondering I there was a way around this.

The bind is done in the init function of my app class

```py
self.root = tk.Tk()
self.root.bind("<Configure>", self.changeWindowSize)
```

The call back is another class function

```py
def changeWindowSize(self, *args):      
    self.root.update()
    # SOME CALCULATIONS
    # Replace the UI
    self.ui.place_forget()
    self.ui.place(relx=0.25+(0.75 - ui_width)/2, rely=0.05+(0.75 - ui_height)/2, relwidth=ui_width, relheight=ui_height)
```

Edit:
Here is how to reproduce it:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1100x600")

def callback(event):
    root.update()

root.bind("<Configure>", callback)

for i in range(10):
    btn = tk.Button(root, text="Button " + str(i) )
    btn.place(relx=0.1*i, rely=0, relwidth=0.1, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

This issue is now obvious. The root.update causes this behaviour.

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: Thank you so much for you advice, I have now found the issue which was the root.update() function. Still not sure why that causes it but I now removes that from my code. I apologize for wasting your time. Thanks again.

Comment: ***"the issue which was the `root.update()`***: The `<Configure>` event get fired on `.update()` which leads to a endless loop.

Comment: To avoid this sort of thing in future, it is often a good idea to unbind and rebind events when they are called.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl: what do you mean by that? I can't remember the last time I ever needed to unbind an event.

Comment: @BryanOakley Not only in my own code I've seen lots of examples of this to stop callbacks building up. Trying to find a link now...